# Second screen is off after login

Tags: 14.04, multiple-monitors, apple

I am using iMac27 with Ubuntu 14.04

```
Linux 3.13.0-100-generic #147-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 18 16:48:51 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I connected an Apple Thunderbolt Display 27 and **it works well until last week**.

Now, after login it switchs off. I have to go to Nvidia settings and configure it again. There it appears as off. I choose its position and On and then apply.

But this configuration is not saved somehow. I tried to Save to X Configuration file, but no progress.

Also, after login (second monitor is off) I fixed it using `xrandr --output DP-4 --auto --panning 2560x1440+2560+0`.

Any idea how to keep it On after login session (maybe **without** running the `xrand` code on some script)?

Comment: As a possible workaround: does `xset dpms force on` turn the screen on (after startup, run from a terminal)? If so, you could add the following to startup applications: `/bin/bash -c "sleep 15 && xset dpms force on`. If that works, you can reduce the `sleep` -time until it stops working. If it works, I'll post it as an answer (+explanation).

Comment: @JacobVlijm, nothing happens with `xset` (even with `sudo`).

Comment: Ah, that's ugly. What is the output of xrandr? (when just logged in).

Comment: Waitwait, I just read your update..  Add to Startup Applications: `/bin/bash -c "sleep 15 && xrandr --output DP-4 --auto --panning 2560x1440+2560+0"` (including quotes). That should fix it.

Comment: From DP-0 to DP-4 and only 2 and 4 connected and 2 is primary.

Comment: I have just read about `monitors.xml` on `.config` folder. Could it help?

Comment: You could always remove it, immediately log out and back in, but ususally it doesn't work. Probably your graphics driver got updated, introducing a small incompatibility, causing the issue. A workaround is then the pragmatic thing to do.

Comment: I moved `xml` file and restarted. Now it works and no new `xml` file was created. Well, lets see what happens. Thanks anyway.